# Webpack - omit creation of LICENSE.txt files

Tags: webpack

I'm using Webpack 5 and along with the `bundle.js` file a `bundle.js.LICENSE.txt` file is created which is not needed, because https://github.com/codepunkt/webpack-license-plugin is used for this task.

Is there any way to configure Webpack to omit the creation of `LICENSE.txt` files?

I've searched the webpack docs, SO and several issues on GitHub but didn't find anything helpful.

Comment: This happened to me when  I removed the license prop from `package.json`. When I added it back, it didn't seem to generate this license file anymore for `.js` files but not for `.tsx` files that are compiled into js

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Add `extractComments: false` to `webpack.config.js`

```json
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
.
.
.
module.exports = {
.
.
.
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [new TerserPlugin({
      extractComments: false,
    })],
  },
.
.
.
};
```

Comment: FYI: This still leaves the license comment inside the bundle itself.

Comment: @SámalRasmussen: So these licenses are really needed inside the bundle? Should we remove them?

Comment: Whether you need to distribute the license with the software is a question of law, not software. So I'm not qualified to answer that for you. It also depends on the license.

Answer (score 48):

To properly remove both the license file and the comments inside the bundle use:

```
optimization: {
  minimize: true,
  minimizer: [
    new TerserPlugin({
      extractComments: false,
      terserOptions: {
        format: {
          comments: false,
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
},
```

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin#remove-comments

Comment: Note: `extractComments: false` will omit the creation of a separate LICENSE file and `terserOptions.format.comments: false` will also remove the comments from the bundled output. Using both of these probably violates the license you are using.

Comment: This gives the error `[webpack-cli] ReferenceError: TerserPlugin is not defined`.

Comment: @KrisztiánBalla No one should be trying to decompile a minified file to figure out what the licensing model of the software is. The whole point of a minified file is to deliver the minimum amount of code.

Comment: @AndrewKoster, you have to `npm install terser-webpack-plugin --save-dev` and `const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");` (from https://webpack.js.org/plugins/terser-webpack-plugin)

Answer (score 17):

The webpack documentation only has this
https://webpack.js.org/plugins/terser-webpack-plugin/#extractcomments

```
extractComments: false
```

This helped me get rid of LICENSE.txt

Answer (score 4):

***Yes***, there is a way to configure Webpack to prevent the creation of the `bundle.LICENSE.txt` files in the build output.

Even though Webpack 5 includes the *[terser plugin out of the box](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/terser-webpack-plugin/#extractcomments)*, if you wish to customise it, you will still need to install it as a dependency, and then set the `extractComments: false` in the optimization settings, to stop the license text files being generated.

###### Step 1 - Install the terser plugin as a dev dependency

`npm install terser-webpack-plugin --save-dev`

###### Step 2 - Import the plugin into your webpack.config.js

```js
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
```

###### Step 3 - Add the optimization key and value

```js
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
// ...

module.exports = () => {
  return {
    entry: './src/index.tsx',
    module: {
      // ...
    },
    resolve: {
      // ...
    },
    output: {
      // ...
    },
    optimization: {
      minimize: true,
      minimizer: [
        new TerserPlugin({
          extractComments: false,
        }),
      ],
    },
    plugins: [  
      // ...
    ],
  };
};
```

Once you have done this, the license text files should no longer appear in the build output directory.

You can take a look at these docs for more information: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/terser-webpack-plugin/#extractcomments

Answer (score 2):

Just add a simple custom plugin,
Delete LICENSE.txt after building the file.

install remove library
`npm i rimraf`

```js
const rimraf = require('rimraf');

plugins: [
  new (class {
    apply(compiler) {
      compiler.hooks.done.tap('Remove LICENSE', () => {
        console.log('Remove LICENSE.txt');
        rimraf.sync('./dist/*.LICENSE.txt');
      });
    }
  })(),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Add clean-webpack-plugin and add setting delete license files after build:

```js
new CleanWebpackPlugin({
  cleanAfterEveryBuildPatterns: ['*.LICENSE.txt'],
})
```

Comment: the pattern should be `['**/*.LICENSE.txt']` and `protectWebpackAssets: false` is needed too

Answer (score 0):

For those who like me don't want to use the terser plugin, **it's possible to remove all LICENSE.txt files, just adding to `CleanWebpackPlugin` options: `cleanAfterEveryBuildPatterns: ['**/*.LICENSE.txt'], protectWebpackAssets: false`**. The downside of this approach is that .js vendor chunk files still have comments in the first line referring to the non-existent anymore licence license text files. To get rid also of these comments, **I have created a customized plugin**, which uses clean webpack plugin to remove txt files and also removes comments from vendor chunks:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

class CustomizedCleanWebpackPlugin {
  constructor({
    vendorJsFileRegex = /vendor.*\.js$/,
    licenseCommentRegex = /^\/\*\!.+\.LICENSE\.txt\s*\*\/\s*/,
    licenseTxtFilePattern = '**/*.LICENSE.txt',
    ...rest
  } = {}) {
    this.licenseCommentRegex = licenseCommentRegex;
    this.vendorJsFileRegex = vendorJsFileRegex;
    this.licenseTxtFilePattern = licenseTxtFilePattern;
    this.restCleanWebpackPlaginOptions = rest;
  }

  apply(compiler) {
    new CleanWebpackPlugin({
      cleanAfterEveryBuildPatterns: [this.licenseTxtFilePattern],
      protectWebpackAssets: false,
      ...this.restCleanWebpackPlaginOptions
    }).apply(compiler);

    compiler.hooks.compilation.tap('CustomizedCleanWebpackPlugin', (compilation) => {
      compilation.hooks.afterProcessAssets.tap(
        'CustomizedCleanWebpackPlugin',
        (assets) => {
          Object.entries(assets).forEach(([fileName, source]) => {
            if (fileName.match(this.vendorJsFileRegex)) {
              compilation.updateAsset(
                fileName,
                new webpack.sources.RawSource(
                  source.source().replace(this.licenseCommentRegex, '')
                )
              );
            }
          });
        }
      );
    });
  }
}

module.exports = { CustomizedCleanWebpackPlugin };
```

Answer (score -2):

I solved it this way:

```
import TerserPlugin from "terser-webpack-plugin";
optimization: {
minimizer: [
  (compiler: Compiler): void => {
    new TerserPlugin({
      terserOptions: {
        format: {
          comments: false
        }
      },
      extractComments: false
    }).apply(compiler);
  }
]}
```

See: https://github.com/MarkZhuVUW/ts-react-s3-circleci-employer-tracker/blob/feature/service-worker-notification/webpack.prod.config.ts