# Webpack BannerPlugin Creates Separate License File

Tags: webpack, version, config, bundle

When I use the Webpack BannerPlugin, it adds a comment to the top of the output file, but the comment just says to check another file.

Is there a way using the BannerPlugin or another webpack tool I can insert the version number in the output file itself?

Current Output file:

```
/*! For license information please see main.js.LICENSE.txt */
(()=>{console.log("myjs");})();
```

Need:

```
/*! Current main.js Version: 1.0.0 */
(()=>{console.log("myjs");})();
```

My webpack config:

```js
let config = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: "ts-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"],
  },
};

let mainConfig = {
  ...config,
  entry: {
    main: "./src/index.ts",
  },

  output: {
    filename: "[name].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.BannerPlugin({
      banner: "Current main.js Version: " + PACKAGE.version + " */",
    })
  ],
};

module.exports = [mainConfig];
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this issue by following this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65650316/4871331

In summary: Webpack v5 and up automatically comes with the TerserWebpackPlugin, which optimizes the code. By default it will extract comments into a separate file (including the banner comment).

To get around this, you need to customize the terser to not extract comments.

First, install the plugin:

```sh
npm install --save-dev terser-webpack-plugin
```

Then add the configuration to webpack.config.js:

```js
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {

  //...

  optimization: {
    minimizer: [new TerserPlugin({
      extractComments: false,
    })],
  },

  //...

};
```